# Resources for English morphemes

Tags: resource-request, vocabulary, english

I'm helping a friend learn English, and one of the things I like teaching is morphemes (parts of a word), by explaining the meaning of the morpheme and examples of it being used.

What resources are there for morphemes?

I tried using Wiktionary for looking up a morpheme ([mono-](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mono-#Derived_terms)), but when I tried looking up derived terms, it listed [504 examples](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_words_prefixed_with_mono-), which isn't helpful, because most of the words aren't commonly used. The Online Etymology Dictionary has an [entry](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=mono-) about the morpheme, but doesn't provide examples. A search for [mono](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=mono) was helpful, though searching for [bi](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=bi) wouldn't work as well.

I came across [Interactive Morpheme Dictionary](http://alexandstein.com/main/morphemes), but "mon" only gives the examples "mononucleosis" and "monad", which aren't very useful as my friend is not a doctor or Haskell programmer.

It should provide examples of the morpheme which are commonly used. It doesn't need to provide definitions of the example words. Ideally the resource should be free.

[Related question on English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/270364/is-there-such-a-thing-as-a-dictionary-that-lists-all-the-words-for-a-given-morph)

Answer (score 1):

Not many free, online lists of English morphemes are available, but of those that are, I'll list two of the most robust lists that I found. [This](https://www.pburgsd.net/cms/lib04/NJ01001118/Centricity/Domain/174/List-of-English-Morphemes.pdf) is the first; it includes a list of Greek and Latin suffixes, their meaning in English, and examples of words in which they are used. [This](http://leonsplanet.com/morphemes.htm) is a similar website with a more extensive list that provides the same information as the first (morpheme, meaning in English, examples).

Answer (score 0):

Here are some partial answers:

1. [A list of English prefixes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_prefix#List_of_English_prefixes) from Wikipedia
2. [English suffixes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix)—some samples of suffixes, from wikipedia

Note that the roots or stems are technically also morphemes, there are no lists of English root morphemes available AFAIK.